# How to get a reference of the content window of the parent window from an iframe, when the parent is cross domain

Tags: javascript

I need to so that the iframe can send a postMessage to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Millebi you can do this using following work around.

```
     <iframe id="frmInner" src="http://www.yahoo.com" height="200" width="200" onload="javascript:$.getScript('Scripts/crossdomain.js',function(){ SomeFunction("someparam"); });">
</iframe>
```

Where 
 frminner is the frame that displays [yahoo page](http://www.yahoo.com) in your site and when loaded completely it calls for a javascript file in you domain i-e  crossdomain.js , 
the JS file has  SomeFunction() already defined in it which is called with parameter "someparam". Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it's messy but I could use something like that to set the domain name in the onload. Only problem is $(document).ready runs before onload, but I can use a set timeout. messy, but it will work.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand the problem, but the yahoo page can still not send you a message or even read the location for instance. Right?

Comment: Through this you can execute a script from your site when the yahoo loads, that way you can submit any message/info to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Because of same origin policy, you have no means to know what is happening is the X-domain child frame. Vice-Versa you have no means to send information up.
However if the other domain is friend of yours, you can establish a communication via the cookies. [see also on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4603815/484046)

Comment: I'm using the HTML5 postMessage to communicate, so x-domain is ok. The only problem is I need to know the hostname, I use it to look up a secret so that I know the site has permission to access it. Is it not possible to even lookup the hostname.